# Relations efficiency mongodb relational-storage patterns, when to embed?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Just moved from traditional SQL server to MongoDB and I am trying to figure out which relational storage pattern I should be using, or when to use embed documents?

I will just point out that this is not a discussion If I should use a relational SQL database or a noSQL database, for several reasons noSQL suits the needs of this project more so then SQL databases.

Reason I am asking is that a lot of advice people receive points in the direction of using MongoDB much like how you do on traditional SQL server, and I am wondering if this is advice I should follow or if just a lot of people are stuck in the mind-set of how traditional SQL servers function.

Application I am writing uses A LOT of one-to-many and many-to-many relations (however each entity may only just have a limited amount of child entities), and even more lookups where you have one entity and you want to find its relational counterpart, in the traditional SQL world this is two or tree different tables, where as in MongoDB embedded documents this can be one or two collections. (I am not saying its not possible to achieve this on traditional SQL servers)

Since I am now working with MongoDB rather then SQL server, i'll show an example of the Account system that I use. Which by the way is a "master account" and "user accounts", basically one user must have one master account and one master account can have multiple user accounts.

The following way is how I embedded my additional users into a master account.

```
Account
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    username: "Some users username",
    users: [
        {
            username: "First additional user name"
        },
        {
            username: "Second additional user name"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the more traditionally SQL like way, though requires an additional query.

```
Account (master account)
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    username: "Some users username"
}

Users (user account)
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    account_id: ref Account ObjectId(),
    username: "An additional user name"
}
```

Given that the system currently has 3 000 accounts and a total of 14 000 user accounts any of the above ways will work quite well (on average one master account has 4 or 5 user accounts), however lets say we multiply these numbers by ten-twenty-thirty *sky is the limit* (still only 4 to 5 user accounts per master account) I imagine that one of the above ways are then preferred?

The remainder of the system acts a lot alike, obviously for entities where I have I have hundreds if not even thousands of child entities the traditional SQL like way is preferred or is it? Generally I work with entities that has 10 to 40 child entities.

Lot's of real-time reports are made within the system, and the meat in these reports are often gathered from these relational entities, on SQL server joins to create these reports were mind boggling complex and inefficient, where as on MongoDB a simple query is run that anyone who has slight knowledge of queries can understand (in this case I am talking about embed documents) and currently a hell lot quicker then previously on SQL server, but I am quite new to noSQL and how will the embed approach perform over time when the growth of data is very high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSQL is a data redudancy as optimization approach story.

In Mongo, you should [embed references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) rather than full documents. But you can also embed partial documents. For example, if you need to know both user's `id` and `name`, you won't add a reference containing `id` only but both.

In the other hand, `users` collection will contain full user documents with more data (i.e. email, date added, date modified...). That is, if you need extended data, you just need to query `users` collection by the user reference (i.e. `id` property) and that's all.

Nowadays disk storage is very cheap and this is why you need to play with data redundancy as I said above.

Comment: Some great pointers, storage itself is not a problem, but performance have been an enemy of mine for years when building reports that used huge amount of joins when I wanted to gather data from several thousands of entities. These reports are quite top-down heavy working from bottom and up, I can explain further if this is unclear what I mean.

Comment: @Joachim Again, data redundancy is the way to get instant results.